# Start an internal site blog or focus on Facebook and LinkedIn?

Tags: seo, facebook, blog, twitter, linkedin

I am putting together a social media campaign for my company.  We already have a site with 300,000 product pages and I am wonder how effective blogging within the site would be compared to to blogging outside of the site.  We already spend time posting on Facebook and LinkedIn, so if we don't significantly increase our posting effort, would having an internal blog really help us?  Here are my thoughts:

- It may be better to focus one or two SM sites that to dilute our effort.
- There is already a large audience associated with LinkedIn and Facebook.
- We would need to build an audience with our additional blog.
- We already have a lot of content on the site, would the blog help SEO?

Answer (score 4):

Blogs seem to be all the rage. But do they always fit the situation? I would answer that by testing a blog internal within the company to first test if there are enough topics that could be covered as to create new and interesting content consistently and for a prolonged period, and two whether you can plan the keyword usage effectively enough to create an effective audience and appropriate search traffic.

I advise companies often to test blogging within the internal web space to test whether blogging is a good idea. If it is not, then no harm no foul. If it ends up being a good idea, then you have a populated blog ready to deploy. I cannot tell you how many people start out creating a blog, tweeting, and the like to only have it drop off or fall flat publicly.

Once created and before deploying, you can take measures to see if your blog will add value SEO wise. I always advise having an internal copy of your website that allows you to not only test new ideas but also run various SEO tools against. I have tested internal sites by DNSing the internal site using my DNS server and letting the SEO tools think it was the real-McCoy.

Generally, blogs do add value but you do have to commit to them. Have it on your own site and not on another site. Why drive traffic to another domain? I have seen companies use other blogging sites and have trouble converting the new users. All they really end up doing was creating value for a site they do not own. I tested a small blog some years ago and what a difference it made. It only took about 20-30 entries to really drive traffic. It was not my idea to test a blog, but to host some testing results that I was doing on an unrelated topic. I was stunned by the traffic even though it was not something I was ready to commit to. So after the testing was done, I removed it.

Sometimes you just have to try something to know if it is a good idea. You just have to see it before a rational decision can be made. Just do not do it publicly.

Comment: We tried to run an internal blog in the past.  The content was thin at best.  Usually, we just commented on what we were working on at the moment or posted pictures.  There was no on-going story or dialog.

Comment: I honestly believe that every one or every entity/organization has a unique value/perspective and voice. What seems to be the challenge is finding what their unique/perspective is. It can be a struggle. But once found, blogs bloom. I have seen this time and time again. Practicing privately allows you to find that value/perspective with no real cost. Once you find it, blog for a while to tune your skills a bit, then publish the blog and keep writing. Just think "What is it I know that is not being said?" or "What is being said that is simply not true?"

Comment: I will give an example. My prior experience was as an IT and business consultant, but my value proposition was a research scientist which is my base skill. My micro-blog was about what was actually true about resume advice, advice given by HR, and what actually works when looking for a job. If someone followed the popular advice of the day, they would never get a job. I created test cases, recruited people, and gathered metrics to find what the truth was. It was something I could do. I could prove my propositions and give a road map to success. And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the fact that the reach of Facebook pages gets weaker each day I would go with a blog on a domain that I can control - you can always share articles on social media.

Facebook is good for communicating with customers, but I would not use it as a blog as I would loose control over my content.

Creating a company blog is a matter of 2 hours of work - install WordPress, add Yoast SEO plugin, buy a decent theme and start writing articles.

It is also important to note that sometimes quality is better than quantity. Look at keywords and phrases in AdWords Keyword planner that people are searching for and make short interesting articles for that. Facebook is good for the masses but you do a lot of work (if you actively communicate with "fans") and the return on investment may be low.

Interesting links:

- [Facebook slashing organic reach](http://www.adweek.com/news/technology/facebook-reportedly-slashing-organic-reach-pages-156417)
- [Facebook ending free ride](http://valleywag.gawker.com/facebook-is-about-to-make-everyone-pay-1547309811)

Your own domain = your own rules + control over costs.

Comment: Keeping control of the content is a very good point.

Comment: Social media websites are simply channels by which you can promote your original content that is placed elsewhere.

Comment: I sounds like I need to have a strong 'core' of information which I create and manage on my site and use Facebook and linked-in to refer to that information.

Comment: Precisely. I have never been a big fan of Facebook. It seems now that they want to capitalize on their position which if they are not careful, will disappear. Use it. But I am not sure how much I would invest sweat-equity and value into Facebook.

Comment: You are probably planning on building a good brand name - would you trust Facebook, LinkedIn or anyone else with full control of your online business?